# outputing ruby strings in js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am making some ajax call and in my `js.erb` file I put

```
$("body").append(<%= escape_javascript(render("layouts/some_layout")) %>);
```

I had no output in my html file, but in my log, `render("layouts/some_layout")` is correctly called. So for debugging purpose, I put

```
 $("body").append(<%= j "<div>test</div>" %>);
```

But this also output nothin. Why is it so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you should have your erb code enveloped with quotation marks, otherwise you'll probably get JS syntax error:

```
$("body").append('<%= escape_javascript(render("layouts/some_layout")) %>');
```